# Add a style to a particular word in a textField data in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

How do I add a specific style (like bold, strike-through) to a word or a sentence in the `textField` data in `JasperReports`

Answer (score 4):

Set `Markup=styled`. Text field has to be a string, so you need to input your style opening tag, concatenate dynamic data and finally concatenate the closing tag.

Examples:

```
"<b>" + $P{parameter_name} + "</b>"

"<font face='DejaVu Serif'>" + $R{resource_name} + "</font>"

"<style size='16'>" + $F{field_name} + "</style>"
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this isn't actually possible. You only have the option of styling text in this way with a static text field (with the styled text option on). Styled text fields can be styled with italic/bold text etc. using HTML type tags.

Text fields though don't allow such styling as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

In iReport 2.0.5 and higher versions there is a option called 'Mark up' by which jasper parses html content, using which different styles can be applied to each word in a textfield expression.

Eg:-
Stanley</span>"]]>

Answer (score 0):

I referred http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/509330/pdf-has-no-bold-or-italics. and it worked out for my requirement, because i only needed to normal text/ bold/ italic in dynamic field.

```
<style pdfFontName='Times-Bold'>to the beneficiary Mr./ Ms./ M/s. </style><style pdfFontName='Times-Italic'>" + $F{BENE_NAME} + " </style>on "
```